# Do we need PHPMailer?

Tags: 7, emails

We are building our website in Drupal 7. However, I wonder whether we need to configure and setup the [PHPMailer](http://drupal.org/project/phpmailer) module.

We are designing an ecommerce website that will send an email upon registration, online purchase, forum activity, etc.
We are confused about whether we need to configure PHPMailer in Drupal 7 or we can make use of Google SMTP services. We are totally clueless about this as we have been struggling to setup the PHPMailer.

Comment: Update posted to Chris's reply

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need PHPMailer. You *will* need an SMTP server of some description.

If your server is Linux, you will need to install some method of sending email such as postfix. You could either let the server distribute email itself, or configure postfix (or whatever) to relay it to another email server.

If it's Windows, I believe you can configure PHP to use an external SMTP server without needing one on the Drupal server itself.

If you were set on sending messages through Google's SMTP servers, you will probably want to use PHPMailer, as it's set up to make that sort of thing easy. Getting hold of your own SMTP server is not tremendously difficult, however.

Can you tell us more about your hosting environment? Maybe we could be more specific with the answer.

Comment: Thanks Chris for feedback, it definitely clears quite a few things for us. 

We want to be able to send email to our clients whenever they purchase, or 'like' something, subscribe to a feed etc etc. 
At the moment, we are building the website on locally hosted server (on Windows 7) but at the time of going live, want to host the website on Google App. Engine & use Google SMTP for our mailing needs. So from your reply, I suppose we DO need to configure PHPMailer.

The problem we get... (continued in the next post).

Comment: (continued from the post above)

The problem we get...
 with PHPMailer is that we get the following:
"Please download PHPMailer for PHP5/6, extract the archive and copy the contents to the following location:
. Make sure the main file, class.phpmailer.php, is located at
/class.phpmailer.php. (Currently using PHPMailer library Missing)"

Comment: If this is a specific problem, could you raise this in a separate question please?